# Expresso Store: Custom PDF generation

Tags: expresso-store

Is it possible to customise PDF generation when, eg, generating PDF Reports?
Client is wanting to know if it is possible to append custom information to the PDF report, eg packaging information and returns information which they are using for packing slips with client orders.

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution for this? I'm wanting to customize the Order PDF and curious what options are out there.

Comment: Hi Adrian - sorry, didn't progress any further with this. Sorry

Comment: I also want to know that whether it is possible to customise PDF generation .I have only tried [process pdf](http://www.rasteredge.com/how-to/csharp-imaging/pdf-processing/) files using a pdf program.Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Yes, its possible but you would need to put some hack into Store module. As I know there is a file within "views" which can be modified for the same. I 'll investigate a little if can share more info.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no. You can't customize the PDFs, because the current reports aren't really customizable. You would need to create an add-on for Store, like [Custom Inventory Columns](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/store-custom-inventory-columns) did or export the data and create custom reports on your desktop. You could possibly also create custom report layouts just using the Query Module in EE, and make them protected pages for your client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out PDF Press? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/pdf-press

There are a few other options, too, including writing your own code if you're feeling adventurous.

Comment: Ah! Just saw the "Expresso Store" tag on this. Sorry if that add-on isn't helpful in this case then.